# Unable to click on element using (R)Selenium

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rselenium

I ma trying to find element using RSelenium

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L,
                      browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
url <- "https://sudskapraksa.csp.vsrh.hr/decisionPdf?id=090216ba8084ca52"
remDr$navigate(url)
```

There is a captcha image (if you don't see it try to execute navigate part 10 times) I tried to select using:

```
  captcha_element <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "img[id='captchaImg']")$clickElement()
  captcha_element <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "captchaImg")$clickElement()
  captcha_element <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*[@id='captchaIm']")$clickElement()
```

but it always return an error.

Comment: `trying to find element` .. which element exactly?

Comment: captcha image. lets say you want just click on captcha image. If you don't see captcha try to execute navigate part 10 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code trials and subsequent comment update to identify the **captcha image** you can use the following *Locator Strategy* but of-coarse you **can't invoke** the **`click` event** as none of the element attributes contain any such event :

```
captcha_element <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "img#captchaImg")
```