# How to click elements correctly

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, xpath, rselenium

In the website, https://www.napaonline.com/, how do I click on the button named "Find an Autocare Center"? It is located at the bottom right. I've tried

```
web_driver$findElements(
  using = "xpath", 
  value =
```

With different paths in the `value` argument without success.

---

```
driver <- rsDriver( 
  browser = c("chrome"), 
  chromever = "114.0.5735.90", 
  verbose = T, 
  extraCapabilities = list("chromeOptions" = list(args = list("--headless"))) 
) 
web_driver <- driver[["client"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the HTML:

```
<button class="nol-button mobile-fullWidth marg-xsv-vrt-md yellow change-my-store-link" data-facilitytype="autocare">Find an Autocare Center</button>
```

To click on the ***clickable*** element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  button[data-facilitytype='autocare']
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  //button[@data-facilitytype='autocare']
  ```

---

### Solution

Your effective code block will be:

```
web_driver$findElements(
  using = "xpath", 
  value = "//button[@data-facilitytype='autocare']"
```

---

### Update

To click on the element <kbd>Find an Autocare Center</kbd> you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *css selector*:

  ```
  FindanAutocareCenter <- web_driver$findElement(using = "css selector", "button[data-facilitytype='autocare']")$clickElement()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *data-facilitytype* attribute:

  ```
  FindanAutocareCenter <- web_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", "//button[@data-facilitytype='autocare']")$clickElement()
  ```
- Using *xpath*, *data-facilitytype* attribute and the text *Find an Autocare Center*:

  ```
  FindanAutocareCenter <- web_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", "//button[@data-facilitytype='autocare' and text()='Find an Autocare Center']")$clickElement()
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Unable to click on element using (R)Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49898439/7429447)

Comment: I get `Error: attempt to apply non-function` when using your suggestion. I'll update what is `web_driver` is, since I think a solution might depend on it.

Comment: No luck. `
Error: Summary: NoSuchElement
Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
Further Details: run errorDetails method`. Same error for the all above alternatives.

Comment: @Nip Add some wait before attempting to click on the element. Using Python similar approach worked for me.

Comment: It think it doesn't even find the element. `Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[data-facilitytype='autocare']"}`. The same happends with other paths.

Comment: `Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@data-facilitytype='autocare' and text()='Find an Autocare Center']"}`.

Comment: I just realized that I need to "verify you are human".